# Generate module function documentation like struct methods

Tags: rust, documentation

How can I generate documentation for module functions so that all the contents of the documentation is shown on the same page like struct methods?

This is probably better described through some screenshots.

Here are some module functions, notice how only the top line of the function documentation is shown on the same page, to see the rest you would have to click each function.
[image: Module functions documentation page]

---

However, the methods inside a struct has all of their documentation on the same page.
[image: Struct methods documentation page]

Question is how can I have functions generate documentation the same way as methods (i.e. all the documentation on one page).

Comment: Why don't you write those functions as `Response`'s methods? Like `Response::new_empty`, `Response::new_permanent_redirect`, `Response::new`, etc.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I suppose that is a solution, though I'm more looking for some solution that doesn't involve refactoring the code that much, for example when I want to generate some docs for other crates.